# Toughening of PMMA

Tags: polymers

For an experimental design with UV-activation I have moulded some UV-transparant (from ~250 nm up) PMMA sheets that I then cut and drill to my final mould. As expected, the PMMA sheets fracture easily and can only used for several experiments. To overcome this I would like to toughen the PMMA while maintaining its UV-transparancy. What would be a good additive for this?

Comment: Are you absolutely restricted to PMMA?